# Rewrite attributes from variables in netCDF

Tags: variables, url-rewriting, netcdf, nco

i want to rewrite some existing time attributes in a correct dateformat to use them for my analysis. I have got no programming experience so where should I start with which programm etc.?

Thanks forward!
Greetings,
Andrea

Comment: yep it helps but is that a programm? where can i download it?

Comment: I just installed cygwin now. Its a Desktop terminal what should I write inside to activate the CDO option?